# integrating mail server with watson discovery service for incoming mails

Tags: ibm-watson

Good day,
Please, I am currently creating machine learning model in Watson knowledge studio and need to test with blind data loaded. Please need some help on how to connect / integrate mail server with Watson discovery service for making sense out of the incoming mails,

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl URLs and index them using the IBM Watson Discovery Service Indexing plugin for [Apache Nutch](https://github.com/IBM-Watson/nutch-indexer-discovery). The crawl does not update automatically, so the procedure will need to be repeated periodically to keep the index up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks alot RiyaMRoy, I actually want to integrate with exchange server or office365 mailbox. however, the link you provided only cover for URL base CRAWL. if this same guide can work for mail server where will I configure the mail server hostname, username and password.